# Aspose.Cells wrap the terms between triple double quotes

Tags: asp.net, csv, aspose, aspose-cells

Using Aspose.Cells I need a csv file with my terms wraped between double quotes. For some reason the terms after the first column are surrounded by triple double quotes when saving my csv file, like: """term"""

This is my code:

```
WorkbookDesigner wd = new WorkbookDesigner();
wd.Workbook.Initialize();
Worksheet sht = wd.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
string value = "term";
value = string.Format("\"{0}\"", value);
sht.Cells[row + rowOffset, column].PutValue(value);
wd.Save(fileLoc, FileFormatType.CSV);
```

I'm using Aspose.Cells version 4.8.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a CSV file with your term as

"term"

then you should save it in your CSV file as

"""term"""

Please type

"""term"""

in a notepad and save it as .csv file. Now open it in Microsoft Excel and see its value, you will find it is displayed as

"term"

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: Well the whole point of using Aspose is that I don't need to create a text file and convert it to csv, do you have any other alternatives?

Comment: As mentioned by the other user Jeronimo, the escape sequence for the quote character is 2 quote characters.

Aspose.Cells is doing the same thing. I have tested it with the following sample code

Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

Cell cell = worksheet.Cells["A1"];

cell.PutValue("\"term\"");

workbook.Save("output.csv", SaveFormat.CSV);

Now, if you open the output.csv in Microsoft Excel, you will see

"term"

and if you open it in a notepad, you will see

"""term"""

Comment: So the only difference between your code and mine is SaveFormat.CSV instead of FileFormatType.CSV?

Comment: @RafaelDiaz both codes are exactly same and will generate the same CSV file. So there is no difference in your code and my code.

Answer (score 0):

In CSV, the escape sequence for the quote character is 2 quote characters.

You are writing the value **"term"** (with quotes). Because of that (your value has quotes), the library will enclose the value with quotes, so you will end up with **"""term"""**.

To make it less confusing and more visible, try writing the value: **some " term ": blah**. This should be printed as:

**"some ""term"": blah"**